# Series radius of convergence

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

We have to find the values of $x$ for which the given series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-4)^n(x-5)^n$ is convergent.

We know that a geometric series converges if $|r| < 1$. We start by expanding:

$1+(20-4x) + (20-4x)^2 + (20-4x)^3 + \ldots$

$|r| = |(20-4x)| < 1$

This is where my question is. The book shows:

$19 < 4x < 21$

Which implies that they added $20$ to both sides. But $20$ is positive. What am I missing?

The book yields:

The series is convergent for: $19/4 < x < 21/4$

Comment: You made a mistake $1+(20-4x) + (20-4x)^2 + (20-4x)^3 + ...$ should be  $1-(20-4x) + (20-4x)^2 - (20-4x)^3 + ...$

Comment: Where is the commands for sigma, exponent, et cetera?

Comment: $(-4)^n(x-5)^n=(-1)^n(4x-20)^n$

Comment: @AndréNicolas. OK but not of $(-1)^n$

Comment: Note that $|20-4x| < 1$ iff $|4x-20| < 1$ iff $-1 < 4x-20 < 1$ iff $19 < 4x < 21$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas. I am sorry ! I have so poors eyes. You and the OP are totally rifght ! Cheers

Comment: Despite the eyesight problem, you have produced many sharp insightful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to deal with the inequality.

One of them is to divide by $4$, and get
$$|5-x|\lt \frac{1}{4}.$$
This says that the distance of $x$ from $5$ is $\lt \frac{1}{4}$, which says that $x$ is between $5-\frac{1}{4}$ and $5+\frac{1}{4}$.

Another way is to unwind the inequality $|20-4x|\lt 1$ as
$$-1\lt 20-4x \quad\text{and}\quad 20-4x\lt 1.$$
The first inequality is manipulated to $4x\lt 21$, which gives $x\lt \frac{21}{4}$. The second inequality is manipulated similarly.

**Remark:** I would recommend looking up the Ratio Test or (better here) the Root Test.